# I want to unintall Ubuntu which I installed alongside windows 10

Tags: uninstall

I recently installed Ubuntu 16 alongside windows 10. Now i want to uninstall Ubuntu and without touching windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove it by following the below steps

1. First of all you have to create a windows bootable USB drive.
2. Then go to the Windows Disk Management  or type **`diskmgmt.msc`** in
   run command.
3. Now, you will be able to see all the partitions.
4. Delete the partitions, other than the windows (where you installed
   ubuntu).
5. Now, Plug in the windows bootable USB drive.
6. Then Open the command prompt from the troubleshoot menu.

Enter the following commands in terminal

```
1. bootrec /RebuildBcd
2. bootrec /fixMbr
3. bootrec /fixboot
4. exit
```

This Should be It.

Comment: This should be it for **Legacy/CSM**. A factory installed Windows 10 is always in UEFI mode. No such procedures are required when installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: @CelticWarrior won't you end up in a GRUB rescue prompt?

Comment: @heynnema You won't as long as you select the Windows entry from the UEFI menu. That boots Windows directly whereas "Ubuntu" boots Grub from where - if everything was correctly installed - you can boot both. That's the may difference: In the old days there could be only one bootloader in the MBR so, for dual boot purposes the installation would replace the Windows one with Grub that would chainload the Windows bootloader if required, or Ubuntu. With UEFI several bootloaders can co-exist in the ESP.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'm not sure you've got it right. If you don't put back a standard Windows boot block, you're going to end up in a half-installed GRUB. One half is is the GRUB boot block, the other half (/boot/grub) is missing when the Ubuntu partition got deleted. Yes, you can use the BIOS/UEFI boot menu (using F12 or whatever), but as you describe, when the user turns on their computer, they'll have to hit F12, or they're going to get a GRUB rescue prompt.

Comment: @heynnema Users can and should change the boot boot order permanently at UEFI settings if users want to boot Windows directly from then on. It really no longer matters what's missing for Grub since the partitions has been deleted and its entry in UEFI boot menu should be removed too although having it there is not a problem. By selecting the Windows entry it always boots Windows directly. Users just have to know what they're doing. UEFI is easier (and saner) for multiple boot, as long as manufacturers do not break the standards. This has been commented for years by *oldfred* here and elsewhere

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'm not sure I agree. The user shouldn't have to do anything to default boot into Windows (once the Ubuntu partition has been deleted). Even Pilot6's link in his comment at the top of this page calls out a different procedure that includes bootrec commands. Can you give an example link where oldfred says different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53332/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-heynnema).